# Default time to wait for a deadlock in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql pattern that I'm using:

```py
try:
    print ('111111')
    self.cursor.execute(sql, values)
    print ('222222') # print to see how long timeouts are taking...
except Exception as error:
    # Most likely a deadlock, retry if NumAttemps <= MaxAttempts
    logger.exception(error)
    ...
```

In another mysql client, to simulate a deadlock, I am doing something like this:

```
begin;
select * from records where id='10.5240-D5CF-3' for update;
```

This works, in that it will grab a deadlock and the `mysql` code will go into the `except` block, usually with the error:

```
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')
```

Is there a way to specify how long the `cursor` will wait before it raises the timeout error / or before it 'gives up' if there is a lock? Are both handled by `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`, or are there multiple settings for this?

Comment: A lock wait isn't the same as a deadlock. Which MySQL version? What's the other conflicting transaction? Is ID the primary key of records? Do you definitely need for 'for update' rather than 'lock in shared mode'?

Comment: @danblack 5.7. The `ID` would be the primary key. I don't need `for update`...I'm just using that to simulate a deadlock -- it's not actual production code in the second code block.

Comment: @danblack any further feedback on the above?

Comment: For deadlocks there needs to be two resources acquired in different order by each connection. Does the [example here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/07/07/mysql-deadlocks-are-our-friends/) explain it